# List<String> array in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, loops, arraylist, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox already created but I would like to update the information with data from a List Array.

I currently have the code:

```
java.util.List<String> listNames = empPort.getEmployeeInfo("username");
int itemSize = listNames.size();
```

the empPort is directed to a web service operation which returned a set of values in a List Array.

When using;

```
for(String s : listNames)
{
    combo.add(s, combo);
}
```

This code did not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: You will want to learn to read the API as it's a necessary skill for coding Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combo.[addItem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29)(s);