# Populate JComboBox from List

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to fill a `JComboBox` from a List but I get the combo empty.

What is wrong with code?

```
 List<Rank> rank = GetRanks();
 Vector model = new Vector();

 for (Rank s : rank) {
     model.addElement(new Rank(s.getRankId(), s.getRankName()));
 }
 jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(model);
```

Comment: Please rename to `getRanks`, also why are you using a `Vector` and not an `ArrayList`? And you're building a new `Rank` from an existing `Rank`, which is a little bit weird for me.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Try ![this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642698/liststring-array-in-jcombobox)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with something like

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Rank> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
for (Rank r : rank) {
    model.addElement(r);
}
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(model);
```

or

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Rank> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(rank.toArray(new Rank[rank.size()]);
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(model);
```

Don't forget to make sure you are adding `jComboBox1` to something that is displayable

Comment: Still not working. I tried for (Rank s : rank) {
            jComboBox1.addItem(s.getRankName());
        } and working but I want to add label and value in the combo

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code at a quick glance so:

1. Either the list is empty
2. Something is wrong with your Rank objects
3. You aren't adding your new combo box onto the page

I think 3 is probably the most likely here as you are creating a new one then not doing anything with it. You probably want to change the items in the old one, not create a new one.

Try running your program in a debugger and stepping through your code looking at what it is doing at each step.